# Power series equation with solution $1/e$

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, power-series, transcendental-number-theory

As $e$ is transcendental, there is no polynomial equation with integer coefficients having $e$ as a root.

Are there classical equations of the form

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_ix^i =1$$

that have $e$ or $1/e$ as root, with $a_i\in \mathbb{Z}$ for each $i$?

For $1/e$, is it possible to have $a_i\ge 0$ for each $i$?

Comment: The Taylor series for $\ln(1+x)$ has fractional coefficients, so it doesn't seem to help...but I don't see an obvious argument that settles this.

Comment: To people voting to close: is the answer so obvious? Let's discard the smart-aleck solution $a_0 = 1, a_i = 0$ for $i \geq 1$.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, isn't it obvious that we can cook up such a series for any positive number smaller than $1$? Just take $a_0:=0$ and inductively $a_i$ to be the largest  positive integer such that the partial sum is still smaller than 1?

Comment: @Kostya_I : I had the same idea, recorded in my answer, except it must be the largest, not the smallest. :-)

Comment: I failed to note condition that the coefficients are integers and voted to hastily to close.  Apparently it's too late to retract the close vote, so voted to reopen.

Comment: @Kostya_I, the question uses the word "classical", which could be charitably interpreted here as "coming from a function satisfying a differential equation with rational coefficients". That may make the question more interesting.

Comment: @Kostya_I Yes, thanks very much, but let's perhaps try to be generous as Matt F. suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a_i=0$ for all large enough $i$, then $e$, being transcendental, cannot be a solution to your equation, unless $a_i=0$ for all $i\ge1$. Otherwise, if $a_i\ne0$ for infinitely many $i$, then the series for $e$ cannot converge, given that the $a_i$'s are integers, because then $|a_ie^i|\ge e^i\not\to0$ if $a_i\ne0$.

However, this can be done for $1/e$, as follows: let $a_0:=0$, and then let $a_j:=\max\big\{k\in\{0,1,\dots\}\colon ke^{-j}+S_{j-1}\le1\big\}$ recurrently for $j=1,2,\dots$, where $S_{j-1}:=\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}a_ie^{-i}$. 
Indeed, then for $j=1,2,\dots$ we have $S_j=a_je^{-j}+S_{j-1}\le1$, whereas $S_j+e^{-j}=(a_j+1)e^{-j}+S_{j-1}>1$, so that $1-e^{-j}<S_j\le1$, whence $S_j\to1$ as $j\to\infty$, as desired.

Comment: Any idea for $1/e$?

Comment: @ToddTrimble : I have added the positive answer for $1/e$.